# React Native ID Card Verification scanner

Tags: react-native, registration, mobile-application, verification, react-native-camera

Is there a free library available for implementing an ID card verification scanner in React Native? This is similar to the functionality where users register in an app and need to validate their identity by scanning a valid ID. Thank you in advance.

I've come across Blink ID for React Native, but it doesn't quite meet my requirements.
Could you provide information on any paid libraries that are available for this purpose? Please help me in finding an alternative solution.

Comment: hello Good morning 
you can check this : https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:card%20scan

Answer (score 0):

One option is `scanovate` - https://scanovate.com/
Support react native